# Objective-C compiler error

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

Need help with the [currentValue, targetValue, difference]; line. It says that initializer element is not a compile-time element. Please post solution.

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"The value of the slider is: %d\nThe target value is: %d\nThe difference is: %d",
                         [currentValue, targetValue, difference];
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]]
                              initWithTitle:@"Hello, World!"
                              message:message
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Comment: please format the post to make the code format look better...

Answer (score 4):

Should be:

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"The value of the slider is: %d\nThe target value is: %d\nThedifference is: %d", currentValue, targetValue, difference];

UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello, World!"
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

You have an extra '[' before current and and extra ']' after the UIAlertView alloc.

Comment: Actually, you only need to remove the `[` before `currentValue`. And there is an extra `]` in the `UIAlertView` line too.

Comment: I think that's what I meant to say; Cleaned up the answer to clarify. Thanks.